# opendistro/opensearch: equivalent of DATEDIFF() function?

Tags: sql, datetime, opensearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I'm using the doc https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/sql/functions/#date-and-time and https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/sql/functions/#date-and-time but haven't found any function like [`DATEDIFF()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/sql-functions-datetime.html#sql-functions-datetime-diff)
in elasticsearch.

I also tried the arithmetic operator with date typed column and it doesn't seem to work either (This query is not explainable):

```
SELECT timestamp(end_date) - timestamp(start_date) FROM <table>
```